# copy tenant from one db to another

Tags: junit, sap-commerce-cloud

is it possible to copy e.g. the junit-Tenant from DB1 to DB2 and if yes, how?

The thing is that I don't want to lose my testdata when I connect to another database (which currently has no junit-tenant initialized)

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using Impex (but it might arise some errors) and you have to do passwords separately (AFAIK at least).
Also, hybris never delete fields in DB. You have to remove attributes from DB1 that might have been created in the past but are not part of the data model any more (thus not created on DB2).

### Export (without passwords) :

1. System -> Tools -> Script Generator
2. Click on "Generate"
3. Copy the result content.
4. remove these fields from the script: [@password, encodedPassword, password, passwordAnswer,passwordEncoding,passwordQuestion] from the generated scrip
5. Go to System -> Tools -> Export
6. Choose mode (re)import relaxed
7. Paste the previously copied script
8. Click on save
9. Click on Run
10. When finished, download the target results (data + media zip files)

### Export Passwords :

12. Go to System -> Tools -> Export
13. Choose mode (re)import strict
14. Paste the content of this :

    ## -------------------------------------------------------

    ## # used 'header validation mode' during script generation was: import_strict

    "#% impex.setLocale( new Locale( ""en"" , """" ) );"

    ## -------------------------------------------------------

    ## ---- Extension: core ---- Type: User ----

    "#% impex.setTargetFile( ""User.csv"" );"
    insert_update User;&Item;@password[translator=de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.translators.UserPasswordTranslator];encodedPassword;password;passwordAnswer;passwordEncoding;passwordQuestion;uid[unique=true,allownull=true]
    "#% impex.exportItems( ""User"" , false );"

    ## ---- Extension: core ---- Type: Customer ----

    "#% impex.setTargetFile( ""Customer.csv"" );"
    insert_update Customer;&Item;@password[translator=de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.translators.UserPasswordTranslator];encodedPassword;password;passwordAnswer;passwordEncoding;passwordQuestion;uid[unique=true,allownull=true]
    "#% impex.exportItems( ""Customer"" , false );"

    ## ---- Extension: core ---- Type: Employee ----

    "#% impex.setTargetFile( ""Employee.csv"" );"
    insert_update Employee;&Item;@password[translator=de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.translators.UserPasswordTranslator];encodedPassword;password;passwordAnswer;passwordEncoding;passwordQuestion;uid[unique=true,allownull=true]
    "#% impex.exportItems( ""Employee"" , false );"
15. Click on save
16. Click on Run
17. When finished, download the target result

### Import (without passwords) :

- Go to System -> Tools -> Import
- Upload the data zip file in "import file"
- Set local setting to "en" (or the one you used in the export scripts)
- Set model to import relaxed
- Set error mode to ignore
- Click on Next
- Upload the media zip file in "import media"
- Click on start

### Import Passwords :

- Go to System -> Tools -> Import
- Upload the data zip file in "import file"
- Set local setting to "en" (or the one you used in the export scripts)
- Set model to import strict
- Set error mode to ignore
- Click on start

Answer (score 0):

Not without significant effort. There is no easy way.

Best you can do is always initialize your data from impex.